# Installing Open SSH Client Beta on Windows 10 (failure 0x800F0950)

Tags: windows-10, ssh

Trying to install the Open SSH Client (Beta) (described here: https://www.bleepingcomputer.com/news/microsoft/heres-how-to-enable-the-built-in-windows-10-openssh-client/ )

But it looks like it starts to install and then doesn't.  My Optional feature history has Error Code 0x800F0950 but no other explaination and nothing is mentioned in any windows logs... what is the next step to try and make this work?

[image: Optional Feature History with errors]

Comment: For what it's worth, you definitely aren't alone.  I have the same problem.  Build 1709, Developer Mode currently disabled.  I hope they address it soon!

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue with 4 failed attempts to install the beta OpenSSH client just now. I needed to install the optional package "Windows Developer Mode" first. It's in the "Manage optional features" list at the bottom. Once I installed that, I could install the OpenSSH client successfully. Then a reboot and the ssh command was available in the normal command prompt.

Comment: 1st Update: I just removed 'Windows Developer Mode' and was able to install the 'OpenSSH Client (Beta)'. Clearly there's no consistency with this one. @Tim Jester - I had the 'Windows Developer Mode' installed and it still failed multiple times. I've done SFC scan, DISM Health scan and CHKDSK - all were clean; no errors. Removed the Windows Subsystem for Linux and rebooted - still no go. However, I looked at the 'Application' log, parsed through the CBS.log and found these entries. Looks like it's unable to find the specific package for 'OpenSSH Client'. 2017-12-14 10:48:50, Info CBS DLWD: Exp

Comment: @tarund: Please do not post in the “Your Answer” box unless you are posting an answer.  If you are “Jeff Martin” and are trying to provide more information about your problem, then login as “Jeff Martin” and [edit](https://superuser.com/posts/1277137/edit) your question.  Otherwise, what are you updating?

Comment: yea... already had developer mode installed so this isn't definitive. at this point i don't see a reason to uninstall developer mode so i'll wait for more answers

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem by installing the latest windows updates.

I was on a brand new 2019 server, and all updates were not installed yet.
I suspect that this is related to the installation of some .NET 3.5 framework installation, and maybe also to the Dev Insider pack, because windows told that it was just added with the updates.