# Installing OpenSSH Beta (Failed)

Tags: windows-10, openssh

I am trying to enable openSSH client optional feature on windows 10. However, the installation fails with error code 0x800F0954, I also tried to enable windows developer mode but even that failed in my case.

There was a similar question [here](https://superuser.com/questions/1277137/installing-open-ssh-client-beta-on-windows-10-failure-0x800f0950/1277166#1277166); however there is no definitive answer. So, I am posting again to see if anyone has similar experience and any potential solution for this.

[image]

Comment: What version of Windows are you running where OpenSSH is a Beta Windows Feature?  That has not been the case in over a year (18 months).  I would upgrade to 1803, 1809, or 1903 in order to solve your overall problem.  WIthout the log file, which indicates the reason the install failed, this question can't be answered.

Comment: @Biswapriyo, OpenSSH is not listed on optional features panel. I see that others had the issue of not seeing all features all the time.

Comment: @Ramhound I have 1709, which is from a corporate image, Unfortunately this is the latest official image they provide for windows 10. I am not sure where to look for logs to see more details? any help. I also tried to get SSH thorough [Win32-OpenSSH](https://github.com/PowerShell/Win32-OpenSSH/wiki/Install-Win32-OpenSSH) but the AV block the ps scripts for suspicious activity and no way around ti to turn it off.

Comment: It's not listed due to the version you are running.  Your IT Administrator will have to help you solve this problem.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For people with similar issues, I amanged to update my windows to build 1809, however, the installation of OpenSSH faced same long time of process followed by a failure (Error code might have changed from 0x800F0954). I tried all the following ways to enable `OpenSSH`:

- Add/Remove Feature of Windows Settings,
- Running command `OptionalFeatures.exe`,
- Using PowerSheel as outlined in microsoft document [Installing OpenSSH for Windows 10](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/openssh/openssh_install_firstuse) as shown below.

The methods above all suffered from same issue of taking long time and eventually failing.

```
Get-WindowsCapability -Online | ? Name -like 'OpenSSH*'

# This should return the following output:
# Name  : OpenSSH.Client~~~~0.0.1.0
# State : NotPresent
# Name  : OpenSSH.Server~~~~0.0.1.0
# State : NotPresent

# Install the OpenSSH Client
Add-WindowsCapability -Online -Name OpenSSH.Client~~~~0.0.1.0
```

Finally, I stumbled on a tweak that resolves the issue for me and many other people, From [microsoft github issues](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/windowsserverdocs/issues/2074):

> Run gpedit.msc (Group Policy) >> Computer Configuration >> Admin.
>   Templates >> Windows Components >> Windows Update >> Specify intranet
>   Microsoft update service location >> Disabled

Hope this helps people out there with similar experiences.